# How to select a child element in Selector

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, lxml, scrapy

I'm using the HTMLXPathSelector to parse the HTML content. And the target website has a random HTML tags. For example: Its format may be:

```
<div class="doctor_ans">
  <h3>Title</h3>
  <p style="text-align: justify;">
    <span style="font-size: 12px;">
      <span style="font-family: arial,helvetica,sans-serif;">
        <font color="#000000">I would like to get contain here.</font>
      </span>
    </span>
  </p>    
</div>
```

or

```
<div class="doctor_ans">
  <h3>Title</h3>
  <p style="text-align: justify;">
    <span style="font-size: 12px;">
      <span style="font-family: arial,helvetica,sans-serif;">
        I would like to get contain here.>
      </span>
    </span>
  </p>    
</div>
```

or

```
<div class="doctor_ans">
  <h3>Title</h3>
  <p>
    <span style="font-size: 12px;">
      <span style="font-family: arial,helvetica,sans-serif;">
        <font color="#000000">I would like to get contain here.</font>
      </span>
    </span>
  </p>    
</div>
```

or

```
<div class="doctor_ans">
  <h3>Title</h3>
  <p>
    <span style="font-size: 12px;">
        I would like to get contain here.
    </span>
  </p>    
</div>
```

and so on.
Please give me your advice how to parse this content. The HTML tags occur randomly. So, I need a method to get child element to find the final element.

Comment: And the question is? What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

```
hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
hxs.select('div[@class="doctor_ans"]/p[1]//text()').extract()
```

will give you a list of each separate piece of text in the first paragraph in the `doctor_ans` div.

Answer (score 0):

I have more experience using Selenium, but the xpath part should be the same.  Select the child element by using xpath='.//span' and then get the .text of that element.  If child element is empty, discard, move on to next element.